# Compactness of $\{(a_n,b_n)\} \cup \{(a,b)\}$ for convergent sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ in Hilbert spaces $A$ and $B$ respectively. Denote $S_1 = \{a, a_1, a_2,...\}$ and $S_2=\{b,b_1, b_2, ...\}.$

We know $S_1 \times S_2$ is compact in $A \times B$. Is it true that $X:=\{(a,b), (a_1,b_1), (a_2, b_2), ...\}$ is compact in $A \times B$?

I think so since if two sequences converge then so do their products with the same indices. Is there a better way of writing this?

Comment: It is easy to see that $X \subset S_1 \times S_2$. Now show that $X$ is closed.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist But closed + boundedness doesn't imply compactness in a Hilbert space, so different argument is needed isn't it?

Comment: Closed subsets of compact sets are compact. Showing this should not be hard, if you don't already know it.

Comment: $X$ is closed in $A\times B$ and $X\subset  S_1\times S_2.$ So  $X$ is  a closed subset of the  space $S_1\times S_2$. Now $S_1\times S_2$ is a compact Hausdorff space, so any closed subset of it, such as $X$, is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments give a great means for showing that $X$ is compact.  It can also be shown directly from the definition without much difficulty.

Since $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$, any open neighborhood of $(a,b)$ in $A\times B$ contains all but finitely many members of $X$.  Thus if $\mathcal U=\{U_\alpha\}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is some $\alpha$ such that $(a,b)\in U_\alpha$, and thus $(a_n,b_n)\in U_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $n$.  The remainder of the $X$ is covered by finitely many members of $\mathcal U$, and therefore $X$ is compact.